# SQL column unknown on firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird

I start saying I'm new to database, sql and similar so probably the code syntax is wrong...

I have to extract some data from three tables on a firebird database.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA,
    ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1,
    PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA,
    ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO 
FROM 
        (SELECT 
            PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA, 
            ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, 
            PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA 
        FROM PRODUZIONE_T 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ORDINI_T ON 
            PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE 
            INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI ON 
            ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR) 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO
         FROM ANGUTENTI)
    ON ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE = PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC 
    ORDER BY PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA;
```

but i receive this error:

> ERROR: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code =
>   -206 Column unknown ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE At line 20, column 15 Error Code: 335544569

I'm sure that the field `ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE` exists!

why? any suggestion?

The DB is not my creation.
I have to extract some data and import it into excel: this the tables:

In the table `PRODUZIONE_T` we have:

- CODPRODUZIONE (integer PK)
- CODORDINE (integer FK to ORDINI_T.CODORDINE)
- NUMEROCOMMESSA (varchar)
- DATACONSEGNA (timestamp)
- RESPONSABILEUC (integer)

In the Table `ORDINI_T`

- CODORDINE (integer PK)
- CODCLIFOR (varchar(25) FK to angclientifornitori.codclifor)

In the Table `ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI`

- CODCLIFOR (varchar(25) PK)
- RAGIONESOCIALE1 (varchar)

In the table `ANGUTENTI`

- IDUTENTE (integer PK)
- NOMINATIVO (varchar(40)

For every record I have to write a row in excel with `PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA, ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA, ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO`.

`numerocommessa` is Number Order, `ragionesociale1` is Customer name, `Dataconsegna` is a date, `Nominativo` is the name of commercial agent.

This is the VBA code

```
Public Sub UpCommesse()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Driver = "Firebird/InterBase(r) driver"
Host = "Zamberlangest"
Utente = "SYSDBA"
Password = "masterkey"
Database = "Commesse"
'Stringa = "DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;=zamberlangest;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;DBNAME=c:\program files\go2\database\go2.gdb"
Stringa = "DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=\\zamberlangest/c:\program files\go2\database\go2.gdb;DataSource=zamberlangest;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;"

Conn.ConnectionString = Stringa
'On Error GoTo Connect_Error
If Not (Conn.State = adStateOpen) Then
    Conn.Properties("PROMPT") = adPromptNever
    Conn.Open
    Connesso = True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Call Commesse
Exit Sub
Connect_Error:
    MsgBox "Connessione con il server MySQL " & Host & " fallita", vbCritical, "Attenzione"
    Connesso = False
    End
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
Sub Commesse()
Set FoglioCommessa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("commesse")
FoglioCommessa.Cells.Delete
Application.EnableEvents = True
Set RS1 = New ADODB.Recordset
'Query = "SELECT PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA, ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA FROM PRODUZIONE_T LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDINI_T ON PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI ON ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR;"
Query = "SELECT PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA, ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA, ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO FROM (SELECT PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA, ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA FROM PRODUZIONE_T LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDINI_T ON PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI ON ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR) INNER JOIN (SELECT ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO FROM ANGUTENTI) ON PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC = ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE ORDER BY PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA;"
With RS1
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .Source = Query
    .Open
    FoglioCommessa.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset RS1
    .Close
End With
Conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: ANGUTENTI table you have `used only in your INNER SELECT` Query. Hence it is not visible at this line- ON ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE = PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC

Comment: You may add table structures and some description of what you are trying to obtain via this query. You may get better solutions.

Comment: Thanks I updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sub-query from `ANGUTENTI`, you do not include the column `IDUTENTE`, so it is not available for Firebird to perform the join. You should see a sub-query as a virtual table that only contains what is selected, so you need to explicitly specify that column in the select list.

You also need to add an alias to the sub-query for it to be usable, because otherwise you'll just have a 'nameless' virtual table, so it can't be referenced.

However your sub-queries are not really necessary, you could also just reference the tables instead

Use:

```
FROM PRODUZIONE_T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDINI_T 
    ON PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE 
INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI 
    ON ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR 
INNER JOIN ANGUTENTI
    ON ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE = PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC
```

Note that the left join on `ORDINI_T` is implicitly converted to an inner join because you use columns from `ORDINI_T` in the subsequent inner join to `ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI`.